# How to evenly space out Views in a HStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a HStack within my view that is supposed to display View contents, with all of them having spaces in between elements:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var element_1: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    
    var element_2: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    
    var element_3: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            element_1
            Spacer()
            element_2
            Spacer()
            element_3
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

which shows the following:

[image]

However when there are many more views (element_1, element_2, ..., element_7), the HStack becomes bit hard to read since there's too many `Spacer()` in the HStack which needs some refactoring:

```
// Example of having 7 element Views, with 8 spacers in:

HStack {
    Spacer()
    element_1
    Spacer()
    element_2
    Spacer()
    element_3
    Spacer()
    element_4
    Spacer()
    element_5
    Spacer()
    element_6
    Spacer()
    element_7
    Spacer()
}
```

I had tried to implement a custom `SpacedHStack` to achieve the same output in order to reduce the HStack into

```
SpacedHStack {
    element_1
    element_2
    element_3
    element_4
    element_5
    element_6
    element_7
}
```

with the following struct:

```
struct SpacedHStack<Content: View>: View {
    var views: [Content]

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.views = [content()]
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(views.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                views[index]
                if index != views.count - 1 {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is not the same as the previous HStack with `n+1` spacers with `n` element Views:

[image]

The previous implementation of `n+1` spacers for `n` elements helped to allow the elements to position themselves for any iPad dimensions which a set length `HStack(spacing: 30){ ... }` would not work (unfortunately there's no such thing as `HStack(spacing: Spacer()) { ... }`). However, this makes the code harder to read due to the many `Spacer()`'s in the HStack. What could be done in the custom `SpacedHStack` to get the same output as previously done? Alternatively, is there an elegant solution to refactor the HStack so that it doesn't need a custom `SpacedHStack` struct?

Comment: what if you use `HStack {...}` in your `SpacedHStack`?

Comment: How does your solution *not* "allow the elements to position themselves for any iPad dimensions"? Can you show an example on an iPad where your solution is different from hand-writing all the `Spacer`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reduce the vertical screen space that all those `Spacer()`s occupy, you can extract this into a view modifier:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func withSpacer() -> some View {
        self
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Then you can add the spacers "inline":

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    element_1.withSpacer()
    element_2.withSpacer()
    element_3.withSpacer()
    element_4.withSpacer()
    element_5.withSpacer()
    element_6.withSpacer()
    element_7.withSpacer()
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't mind using underscore-prefixed APIs, you can extract each view in a `ViewBuilder` using [View Extractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor).

```
struct HStackWithSpacers<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                ForEach(views) { view in
                    view
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thought not an ideal solution (not in the form of `X { element_1; element_2; element_3; ... }` where X is another defined struct), your View extension allows more @ViewBuilder spacer functions defined in the extension like `Spacer(); self; Spacer()` for a `sandwichedSpacer()` or `Spacer(); self; ` for a `topSpacer()` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are is no need for 3rd parties or private libraries. Apple provides a sample of this in their WWDC  videos.

```
struct MyEqualWidthHStack: Layout {
    /// Returns a size that the layout container needs to arrange its subviews
    /// horizontally.
    /// - Tag: sizeThatFitsHorizontal
    func sizeThatFits(
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) -> CGSize {
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return .zero }

        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let totalSpacing = spacing.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }

        return CGSize(
            width: maxSize.width * CGFloat(subviews.count) + totalSpacing,
            height: maxSize.height)
    }

    /// Places the subviews in a horizontal stack.
    /// - Tag: placeSubviewsHorizontal
    func placeSubviews(
        in bounds: CGRect,
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) {
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return }

        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)

        let placementProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height)
        var nextX = bounds.minX + maxSize.width / 2

        for index in subviews.indices {
            subviews[index].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: nextX, y: bounds.midY),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: placementProposal)
            nextX += maxSize.width + spacing[index]
        }
    }

    /// Finds the largest ideal size of the subviews.
    private func maxSize(subviews: Subviews) -> CGSize {
        let subviewSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        let maxSize: CGSize = subviewSizes.reduce(.zero) { currentMax, subviewSize in
            CGSize(
                width: max(currentMax.width, subviewSize.width),
                height: max(currentMax.height, subviewSize.height))
        }

        return maxSize
    }

    /// Gets an array of preferred spacing sizes between subviews in the
    /// horizontal dimension.
    private func spacing(subviews: Subviews) -> [CGFloat] {
        subviews.indices.map { index in
            guard index < subviews.count - 1 else { return 0 }
            return subviews[index].spacing.distance(
                to: subviews[index + 1].spacing,
                along: .horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Find the video

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10056

And the code for an HStack, VStack and Radial Layout

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui

This code will be used just like a regular `HStack`

```
MyEqualWidthHStack {
    //Your views here
}
```

Note that this solution will also work with `ViewThatFits`

```
    ViewThatFits {
        MyEqualWidthHStack {
            Buttons(pets: $pets)
        }
        MyEqualWidthVStack {
            Buttons(pets: $pets)
        }
    }
```

And `AnyLayout` which allows you to conditionally apply a `Layout`

```
 let layout = isThreeWayTie ? AnyLayout(HStackLayout()) : AnyLayout(MyRadialLayout())
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve code refactoring with ForEach loop.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            ForEach(0..<7, id: \.self) { item in
                CircleItemView()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}

struct CircleItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a solution which also allows to decide if displaying Views **horizontally** or **vertically**. I've built a reusable View which takes in the number of times an element should be rendered, whether to apply an inital `Spacer` before each new content render, and the **content** to render itself:

```
struct EquallySpacedStack<Content: View>: View {
    var numberOfElements: Int
    /// Uses an HStack if true
    var isHorizontal: Bool = true
    /// If true it will use Spacers before and after the content is rendered
    var applyInitalSpacer: Bool = true
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isHorizontal {
                HStack {
                    renderContent()
                }
            } else {
                VStack {
                    renderContent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func renderContent() -> some View {
        ForEach(0..<numberOfElements, id: \.self) { index in
            if applyInitalSpacer {
                Spacer()
            }
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
EquallySpacedStack(numberOfElements: 5, isHorizontal: false) {
    Circle()
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 100)
}
```

This will produce the following result:

[image: Vertical Equelly Spaced Content]

While this code:

```
EquallySpacedStack(numberOfElements: 3, isHorizontal: true) {
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```

Would produce this:

[image: Horizontal Equally Spaced Content]

I think the best solution would be a combination of this and what [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) suggested. That is, using [ViewExtractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) to have either any View rendered or, using the numbered strategy as I have done here. I think I will try improving it with `ViewExtractor` later today.