SwiftUI HStack inner Views have fill entire width equally and have same height, regardless of the content
So I just need the views within an HSTack to each take the entire width available to them so the space is evenly distributed and all have the same width.
As for height, they should also all have the same height regardless of text length.
Current code:
struct TestViewHStack: View {
    
    let strings = ["Short", "some long text", "short"]
    
    var body: some View  {
            HStack {
                ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { title in
                    CardView(title: title)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct CardView: View {
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
            .padding(16)
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.2), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
    }
}

Output:

I thought setting .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) would make it each take the entire width available, but it doesnt seem to do that. Also tried messing with frames and fixedSize() modifiers but wasnt able to achieve the desired result.
Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78085491/how-to-evenly-space-out-views-in-a-hstack/78087642#78087642

Thank you for the reply but it doesnt seem to be working at all + cant really use the Layout API as its iOS 16 only and Im currently supporting iOS 15, sadly.

For the width, you were doing it the right way by using maxWidth: .infinity, except that this needs to be applied before the background and other decorations (like shadow and clip shape). So:

you can either move the .frame modifier from TestViewHStack to CardView
or, you could move all the decoration from CardView to TestViewHStack.

The first way involves less changes (but see the note about reusability after the screenshot below).
For the height, I would suggest one of the following two techniques:

If you want to fix the maximum number of lines to a certain number, say 2, then you could use the technique shown in the answer to How do I have achieve a combined line limit for two Text views in a VStack in SwiftUI? and reserve the space that will be needed:

Text(title)
    .font(.subheadline)
    .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true)


If you just want to use the minimum space necessary, then the space needed can be established using a hidden version of the same content. The hidden version forms the footprint and its height will be the height of the tallest card. The visible content is then shown as an overlay over the footprint.
An overlay is constrained by the size of the view it is applied to, so maxHeight: .infinity can be used to have all the cards expand to the full height of the overlay, this being the height of the tallest card. Use alignment: .top if you want the stars to be aligned at the top:


struct TestViewHStack: View {

    let strings = ["Short", "some long text", "short"]

    private func cardRow(fullHeight: Bool = false) -> some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { title in
                CardView(title: title, maxHeight: fullHeight ? .infinity : nil)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View  {
        cardRow()
            .hidden()
            .overlay{
                cardRow(fullHeight: true)
            }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let title: String
    let maxHeight: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
            .padding(16)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: maxHeight, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.2), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
    }
}


If you are concerned that moving maxWidth: .infinity into CardView stops it from being reusable, then you could always make maxWidth a parameter of type CGFloat? in just the same way as maxHeight has been parameterized above. You could also support a default of nil, so that it behaves in the same way as you had it before:
struct CardView: View {
    let title: String
    var maxWidth: CGFloat?
    var maxHeight: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                // ...
            }
            .padding(16)
            .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight, alignment: .top)
            // decoration as before
    }
}

This version of CardView behaves exactly the same as you originally had it. When used in the context of TestViewHStack, the function cardRow shown in this answer would need to specify the maxWidth explicitly:
ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { title in
    CardView(
        title: title,
        maxWidth: .infinity,
        maxHeight: fullHeight ? .infinity : nil
    )
}


To the downvoter: a downvote is supposed to mean, "this answer is not useful", which would be fair if it didn't work. But the technique of using a hidden footprint does work and it's perfectly valid. It's a technique that is particularly useful for cases where the content that determines the size is lazy-loaded and not initially visible.

No clue who downvoted, certainly wasnt me! Hi there, thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay in getting back to you. This is actually quite a clever idea. Just to see if I got this right, the reasoning behind this approach is making the initial stack take whatever height it needs to fit the inner views (disregarding wether one is bigger than the other or not) and then hide it so you are only left with the footprint. Once thats done re render the views again but now setting an infinity frame so each takes the height of the highest card of the footprint. If so, thats super clever indeed.

This approach allows to avoid having to manually calculate the size of each card via either GeometryReaders or PreferenceKeys, right? I mean, without this "technique", one would have to manually calculate the frame, correct? Again, thank you! I wouldnt have been able to come up with such technique myself, super interesting!

@stompy Correct, no GeometryReader or PreferenceKey needed. The hidden version acts as a placeholder which finds its own ideal size, then the visible version (containing the same content) is shown over it, constrained by the frame of the placeholder.

So clever. Thank you once again, much appreciated :)

Thanks for giving it a proper look and understanding how it works. Ps. you would be welcome to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped ;)

Absolutely. Done!

For the width:
They already have the same width, but you cant see it because you apply the height after setting the background. So reorder the modifiers to make it visible:
struct TestViewHStack: View {

    let strings = ["Short", "some long text", "short"]

    var body: some View  {
        HStack {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { title in
                CardView(title: title)
                    // .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //  This is after the background framing
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            Text(title)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding(16)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //  This does the job as expected
        .background(Color.white)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
        .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.2), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
    }
}

Visible Equal Widths Demo:

For the height:
If you just need a fixed height, just add a maxHeight to the frame and control the height of the stack.
But it seems like you don't know the height and you need all items to have the same size with the tallest one. So you need to let them size themselves and update anyone with the shorter height. This is where onPreferenceChange comes in and requires some work.
struct TestViewHStack: View {

    let strings = ["Short", "some long text", "short"]
    @State private var maxCardHeight: CGFloat = 10

    var body: some View  {
        HStack {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { title in
                CardView(title: title)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background {
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Color.clear.preference(
                                key: MaxValue.self,
                                value: proxy.size.height
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    .onPreferenceChange(MaxValue.self) {
                        maxCardHeight = $0
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: maxCardHeight)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                    .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.2), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum MaxValue: PreferenceKey {
    public static let defaultValue = CGFloat()
    public static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) { 
        print("value: \(value), next: \(nextValue())")
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            Text(title)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding(16)
    }
}


Note that you must first size and then apply the background. So You need to rearrange your UI logic

Thank you! I went ahead and replied on a PasteBin as it wouldnt let me write too much here: https://pastebin.com/JdMvnHs2 . Thanks again :)

Some of these requirement are different than what you asked originally but you can use a approach similar to the height for the width to have the same size widths or just get the container size and divide it to the number of items.

About the extracting modifiers, you can inject the needed properties into the the view instead to make it more reusable as you call it.

All of your new requirements are very easy to achieve but they are out of the scope of the original question. You may want to try yourself and then you can ask a new question where you stuck ;)
